# Post to server returns empty via Postman

Tags: php, postman

This is my my index.php file

```
 <?php
  print_r($_POST);
  exit;
?>
```

I'm posting to my website using postman in chrome, but nothing gets there. I get back only

```
Array
(
)
```

I know that postman works because I used it when I had free webhosting. Now I asked a friend for a little space on his website, but for some reason the post data is not printed.How can I solve this ?

Here is a photo with what is happening: http://6pix.net/images/16687663370157764163.png .

Comment: I am getting very good , see here http://s4.postimg.org/mpkwn2yjx/image.png ! Are you pointing to correct page ?

Comment: I know that postman works. On the free webservice that I was using before it worked. Yes, I am posting on the correct page.

Comment: Once again can you output some content to the target page and check if the postman shows it  ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen This time could you explain exactly what you want and not mark my question as off-topic ?

Comment: Your question might be closed as off-topic due to fewer reason listed in faq of the site. But my point would be, what are steps taken by you to debug it ?

Comment: That's why I posted here. I have no idea what to do. The post was working  on the free webhosting server. So I guess it has something to do with the server ?

Comment: Ok, If you have some content in the target page / service can you see it in the browser ? This is to make sure again that you refer exact page and the webservice allows outputing data from its source

Comment: Ok, then next check would be whether it allows to execute php script, make sure that file is a `.php` and try to do `echo` inside it, to make sure that your server runs `php`

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen found the problem. I had to include the full path in postman like `...path/index.php`. I was just including `...path/`

Comment: I did not include the full path because on the free web hosting it was not needed

Comment: Cool, that's great. You want me to write an answer about it to make useful for future readers or not needed ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen yes. That would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here are the Possible Mistakes and the way to debug it

**1. Check if your web server supports `php`**

You can check this by running a `.php` file with some output statements such as `echo`

**2. Check if you are pointing the page properly**

You shall check this by outputting some content

**3. Try with full path**

Some servers needs to get full path i.e., it won't support point the `index.html` or `index.php` if the directory path was given

**Additional Note :**

If the above issues doesn't helps then you might check with the `.htaccess` , blocking of REST Calls etc.,.

Comment: Cheers !! You're welcome, You shall accept the answer if you think it is useful :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did :D :D

Answer (score 0):

If you really (like shown within your screenshot) do

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

please check your php.ini for your

```
request_order
variables_order
```

If "post" is not within that order, $_REQUEST will not have "post" content inside.

Comment: Found the problem. I did not include the full path in postman. I was just using `....path/` instead of  `....path/index.php`